# How to refactor the pervasive if statement for type check

Tags: c#, generics, refactoring, type-conversion

I'm work with a legacy system which has been around ten years, in it one of the basic data structure is defined like below:

```
[Serializable()]
public class DataClass
{
    private Array _values;
    private readonly Type _valueType;

    public DataClass(Array tmpArray, Type tmpType)
    {
        _values = tmpArray;
        _valueType = tmpType;
    }

    public Array GetValues()
    {
        return _values;
    }

    public Type ValueType
    {
        get { return _valueType; }
    }

    public void SetValues(Array newValues, int fromIndex)
    {
        // 1. type check, if _values and newValues don't share same data type, throws an exception

        // 2. length check
        if (fromIndex + newValues >= _values.Length)
           throws new InvalidDataException();

        // 3. set values
        for (var i = fromIndex; i < newValues.Length; i++)
             _values.SetValue(newValues.GetValue(i - fromIndex), i);  
    }

    ...blahblah
}
```

I believe the initiative was they want to support different data types using only one class, e.g.

```
new DataClass(new int[]{1,2,3,4}, typeof(int));

new DataClass(new float[]{1f,2f,3f,4f}, typeof(float));
```

Now I want to init the `DataClass` with default values, after profiling I found that the API `SetValues` is quite slow for longer arrays (`boxing` and `unboxing` I believe) and makes the program less responsive, I decided to use **Generic** and lots of **if else** statement for speeding up, e.g.:

```
void InitValues(DataClass data)
{
    if (data.ValueType == typeof(int))
        InitWith(data, -1);
    else
    if (data.ValueType == typeof(double))
        InitWith(data, -9.99d);

    ...blahblah

}

void InitWith<T>(DataClass data, T defaultValue)
{
    // much faster
    var array = (T[])data.GetValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
         array[i] = defaultValue;
}
```

Yet I got plenty of performance critical methods like `InitValues`.Since there are so many value types that `DataClass` supports, it's irritating to write and maintain such code.

Given the fact that I don't own the source code of `DataClass`, I **can't make any change** to the `DataClass`. I wonder whether there is a way to refactor, so that I can deal with all the `if` statements of type check in **one place**?

Comment: What does `DoSomething` do that it requires the generic type? This is so that I can understand the reason behind why your code is structured to help give an answer.

Comment: Are you allowed to change the *DataClass* ?

Comment: @bit oh no I can't, our system has been around for almost ten years and this `DataClass` is used everywhere.

Comment: @StephenRoss For e.g., we append some values at the end of `data.Values`. When data.ValueType is int, we append integer 1; when double, we insert double 2.0.

Comment: Is DataClass mutable? That is, given one instance, can it sometimes be full of ints and sometimes be full of doubles?

Comment: Are those members public, private, protected?  MethodA and MethodB seem to be accessing properties, not fields; are there wrapper properties around the fields? Are they read-write properties?  There is nowhere near enough information in this question to design you a sensible solution.

Comment: Are you sure you can't change DataClass? If it's just a matter of backwards compatibility (source or binary?) then you can still change it in a non-breaking manner....And wouldn't you need a cast for those DoSomething calls? Or do they just take an Array param and use <T> for something else?

Comment: @EricLippert Thank you for your questions, makes me learn how to ask a specific question here. I've updated more details.

Comment: @MarkBrackett Sorry I've missed some important info here :( More details are added, please take a look.

Comment: Given the restrictions, you seem to be on the right track. You could further speed it up by using a *Dictionary* of *Type* against *Action* and initialize it only for the required types in the consumer class. This will get rid of the multiple *if else* s

Comment: @bit Could you please elaborate on using `Dictionary`? Like `new Dictionary<Type, Action<DataClass, T>>`? I don't think the compiler will let you go :(

Comment: Just added a sample consumer class, in the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your are not allowed to change the `DataClass`, we need to make the consumers of the `DataClass` efficient. One way to do that would be to use Dictionaries to map the Types to the Actions/Methods. We would need to initialize these dictionaries only once. Here is an example to such a class.

```
class ConsumerClass // the one which uses DataClass objects
{
    // All the Mappings required by this consumer class
    readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<DataClass>> InitMap = new Dictionary<Type, Action<DataClass>>();
    readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<DataClass>> DoSomethingAMap = new Dictionary<Type, Action<DataClass>>();
    readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<DataClass>> DoSomethingBMap = new Dictionary<Type, Action<DataClass>>();

    // Constructor
    public ConsumerClass()
    {
        // Initialize all the mappings for all the required types for this consumer class here. 
        // This is a one time overhead, but will definitely speedup the methods within this class
        // You could move this part further up the hierarchy of inheritance, to avoid repetitions in every other consumer class.

        // For int
        InitMap.Add(typeof(int), data => InitWith(data, -1));
        DoSomethingAMap.Add(typeof(int), DoSomethingA<int>);
        DoSomethingBMap.Add(typeof(int), DoSomethingB<int>);

        // For double
        InitMap.Add(typeof(double), data => InitWith(data, -9.99d));
        DoSomethingAMap.Add(typeof(double), DoSomethingA<double>);
        DoSomethingBMap.Add(typeof(double), DoSomethingB<double>);

        // other types, if needed by this consumer
    }

    void InitValues(DataClass data)
    {
        // This takes care of your if s
        InitMap[data.ValueType].Invoke(data);
    }
    void InitWith<T>(DataClass data, T defaultValue)
    {
        // much faster
        var array = (T[])data.GetValues();
        for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            array[i] = defaultValue;
    }

    void DoSomethingA(DataClass data)
    {
        DoSomethingAMap[data.ValueType].Invoke(data);
    }
    void DoSomethingA<T>(DataClass data)
    {
        var array = (T[])data.GetValues();
        // do something
    }

    void DoSomethingB(DataClass data)
    {
        DoSomethingBMap[data.ValueType].Invoke(data);
    }
    void DoSomethingB<T>(DataClass data)
    {
        var array = (T[])data.GetValues();
        // do something
    }
}
```

There is some redundant code in the constructor, so there could still be a better way to write this mechanism. But you should get an idea of how you could clean up your ifs and still improve the performance.

Comment: Okay I see, you're wiring up all the function calls in the dictionary, so there is no `if else` statement anymore. And I suppose in `ConsumerClass`, only `void InitValues(DataClass data)`, `void DoSomethingA(DataClass data)` and `void DoSomethingB(DataClass data)` are public, the rest stays private, right?

Comment: Yep, you are right. You would know the other design aspects of your code,  so you could combine this mechanism with it, in a better way.

Comment: Hi, what if I have a method `T GetData(DataClass)`? How can I define a dictionary for `Func<Data, T>`?

Comment: In that case your method signature would be *T GetData<T>(DataClass data)* and the Dictionary would be exactly same as others.

Comment: Do you mean by `Dictionary<Type, Action<DataClass>> GetDataMap`? But now `T GetData<T>` is not an `Action` anymore

Comment: You would still be able to map it by *GetDataMap.Add(typeof(int), data => GetData<int>(data));*

Comment: E.g. `private T Method<T>()
{
    return default(T);
}

Dictionary<Type, Action> map = new Dictionary<Type, Action>();

map.Add(typeof(int), () => Method<int>());`  So how get I get the return value of `map[typeof(int)]()`?

Comment: Or you could make that a  *Dictionary<Type, Action<DataClass>>* and then see the way *InitMap* is being used..

Comment: Sorry, I think I don't get your idea :( Could you please explain a little bit more? Now I want to have a dictionary like this : `Dictionary<Type, Func<DataClass, T>>`